# Get measure of relative layout android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-studio-2.0

I have an empty `RelativeLayout`. I must get height and width of layout (set to match the parent). I have tried to search online but, to no avail. This is my code, can you help me? When I launch the application it crashes in the getCoordinate method. Sorry for my English.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Random rand = new Random();
int[] coordinate = new int[2];

public void getCordinate(final RelativeLayout layout){
    layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // Ensure you call it only once :
            layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            coordinate[0] = layout.getMeasuredWidth();// width must be declare as a field
            coordinate[1] = layout.getMeasuredHeight();// height must be declare as a fiel
        }
    });
}

public void makeButton(RelativeLayout play_area){
    int button_x = rand.nextInt(coordinate[0]);
    int button_y = rand.nextInt(coordinate[1]);

    Button bomb = new Button(this);
    bomb.setX((float)button_x);
    bomb.setY((float)button_y);
    play_area.addView(bomb);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RelativeLayout play_area = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.play_area);
    play_area.measure(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    getCordinate(play_area);

    Log.d("Coordinate", "Xmax: " + coordinate[0] + " Ymax: " + coordinate[1]);

    //makeButton(play_area);

}
}
```

Comment: It would be useful if you describe what exception is occurring and possibly including the stack trace in your question.

Comment: Don't call measure() on views.  That's the job of the layout manager.  Also, yeah, always post a stack trace if something is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't call measure(). you could maybe just call .setLayoutParams(width, height) to set the view to match parent's width/height.

and simply calling .getMeasuredWidth() (or height) on the view should return their width/height values

Comment: my layout must adapt to the display dimensions. When relativelayput is adapted i must get the dimension in dp of this, .getMeasureWidth() return every 0